# How can ı delete this reflection on the tank

Tags: animation, materials, shaders, glass, reflection

[image: the problem]

As you can see the material I used in the tank reflects the surrounding objects,but I want it to show the reflection a litle bit and shine

[image: shading properties]

there is my shaing properties
what should ı do

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Light Path node, it has plenty sockets that filter the type of rays. Though I think it works only on Cycles. One of them being "Is Reflection Ray", which filters out anything that is a reflection.

Use that node's "Is Reflection Ray", and use it as a factor of a Mix Shader node. In that mix node, plug your glass shader in the first shader slot, and whatever reflection-less shader in the second shader slot.

EDIT: Example screenshot:

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: ım waiting your screenshots thx <3

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/72gos6g.PNG

i think it doesn't work for me ,there is my rendering settings

https://i.hizliresim.com/44thhco.PNG

EDIT : Example screen shot